# Could not find rake-12.3.3 in any of the sources when using fastlane

Tags: ruby, fastlane

when I execute this command to compile my project:

```
sudo bundle exec fastlane beta
```

shows this error:

```
Could not find rake-12.3.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
(base)
```

and I install rake:

```
$ sudo gem install rake
Password:
Successfully installed rake-13.0.3
Parsing documentation for rake-13.0.3
Done installing documentation for rake after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
(base)
```

but still not fix the problem. what should I do to make it work? I already execute bundle install, still not fix it:

```
~/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/ios on  main! ⌚ 17:49:28
$ sudo bundle install
Password:
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.
Using rake 12.3.3
Using CFPropertyList 3.0.3
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using addressable 2.7.0
Using atomos 0.1.3
Using aws-eventstream 1.1.0
Using aws-partitions 1.402.0
Using aws-sigv4 1.2.2
Using jmespath 1.4.0
Using aws-sdk-core 3.110.0
Using aws-sdk-kms 1.39.0
Using aws-sdk-s3 1.86.0
Using babosa 1.0.4
Using bundler 2.2.9
Using claide 1.0.3
Using colored 1.2
Using colored2 3.1.2
Using highline 1.7.10
Using commander-fastlane 4.4.6
Using declarative 0.0.20
Using declarative-option 0.1.0
Using digest-crc 0.6.2
Using unf_ext 0.0.7.7
Using unf 0.1.4
Using domain_name 0.5.20190701
Using dotenv 2.7.6
Using emoji_regex 3.2.1
Using excon 0.78.1
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using ruby2_keywords 0.0.2
Using faraday 1.1.0
Using http-cookie 1.0.3
Using faraday-cookie_jar 0.0.7
Using faraday_middleware 1.0.0
Using fastimage 2.2.0
Using gh_inspector 1.1.3
Using jwt 2.2.2
Using memoist 0.16.2
Using multi_json 1.15.0
Using os 1.1.1
Using signet 0.14.0
Using googleauth 0.14.0
Using httpclient 2.8.3
Using mini_mime 1.0.2
Using uber 0.1.0
Using representable 3.0.4
Using retriable 3.1.2
Using google-api-client 0.38.0
Using google-cloud-env 1.4.0
Using google-cloud-errors 1.0.1
Using google-cloud-core 1.5.0
Using google-cloud-storage 1.29.1
Using json 2.3.1
Using mini_magick 4.11.0
Using plist 3.5.0
Using rubyzip 2.3.0
Using security 0.1.3
Using naturally 2.2.0
Using simctl 1.6.8
Using slack-notifier 2.3.2
Using terminal-notifier 2.0.0
Using unicode-display_width 1.7.0
Using terminal-table 1.8.0
Using tty-screen 0.8.1
Using tty-cursor 0.7.1
Using tty-spinner 0.9.3
Using word_wrap 1.0.0
Using nanaimo 0.3.0
Using xcodeproj 1.19.0
Using rouge 2.0.7
Using xcpretty 0.3.0
Using xcpretty-travis-formatter 1.0.0
Using fastlane 2.170.0
Using fastlane-plugin-pgyer 0.2.2
Using xcode-install 2.6.8
Bundle complete! 3 Gemfile dependencies, 75 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
(base)
```

this is my `Gemfile`:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "xcode-install"
gem "fastlane"

plugins_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'fastlane', 'Pluginfile')
eval_gemfile(plugins_path) if File.exist?(plugins_path)
```

Comment: The error message told you to run `bundle install`, not `sudo gem install rake`. Try running `bundle install`.

Comment: The fact that you ran **`sudo`** `bundle exec...` is ringing alarm bells for me. I think you may have screwed up permissions; you shouldn't need to use `sudo` for any of the commands above.

Comment: Edit: And again, why are you running **`sudo`** `bundle install`? The warning message also tells you: *"Don't run Bundler as root."*. My advise would be to uninstall your (broken-permissions) ruby setup, and start again without using `sudo`.

Comment: I have tried remove `sudo`, still not fix it.@TomLord

Comment: bundle install not fix it. @TomLord

Comment: You tried uninstalling ruby, and re-installing without broken user permissions?